# Datetime column deformes when it is converted to parquet file

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, data-science, parquet

I am working on a csv file which includes a column including dates, but dtype of this column is actually just object so I changed it to datetime. This part went without a flaw data wasn't changed except it's datatype. But when I turn this dataframe into a parquet file it turns every single row into the same date and it is not even in the previous date format.

Date format in csv is "%Y-%m-%d" like 2011-01-29. This is the last few steps after working on the dataframe:

```
df_merged_CA["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged_CA["date"], format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df_merged_CA.to_parquet("merged1.parquet", compression = "gzip", engine = "pyarrow")
```

I checked if date is in the correct form after convertion to datetime and it was, it was still in the form of 2011-01-29. After this I checked the parquet file to see if the date is in correct form, however I see that every date is turned into dates like this 43060-07-05.03:00:00.000 . I saw that problem may be occuring because of the timezone so I changed datetime convertion to this but nothing changed.

```
df_merged_CA["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged_CA["date"],
 format = "%Y-%m-%d").dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
```

Comment: I recently found a similar problem after going a little deeper. This post managed to solve my problem. I will keep this here in case someone comes across the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798479/editing-parquet-files-with-python-causes-errors-to-datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with the assignment to the time zone was already correct. You just have to convert the field with the date into a **string** before you write the data into the parquet file.
You do this with `.dt.strftime()` from pandas package. There you can enter your desired format in the brackets.

### Here is the complete code:

```
df_merged_CA["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged_CA["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

df_merged_CA["date"] = df_merged_CA["date"].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin')

df_merged_CA["date_str"] = df_merged_CA["date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_merged_CA.drop(["date"], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_merged_CA.to_parquet("merged1.parquet", compression="gzip", engine="pyarrow")
```

Comment: Thank you! I already found a way to solve my problem. But I will keep this in mind in case I need it. If you are curious about the solution I found, I added a comment leading to the post including the solution.